# Use mean value theorem to prove two inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, mean-value-theorem

Let $0<x<y$. Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove:

1. $y\ln y - x\ln x\leqslant(y-x)(1+\ln y)$
2. $e^{y^2}-e^{x^2}\leqslant (y-x)(x+y)e^{y^2}$

---

The first inequality is easy. Just consider the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}, f(x)=x\ln x$, then by the MVT, for some $z\in (x,y)$,
$$
f'(z)=1+\ln z=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=\frac{y\ln y-x\ln x}{y-x}.
$$
Since $f'(x)=1+\ln x$ is monotonically increasing and $z<y$, it follows that
$$
f'(y)=1+\ln y\geqslant f'(z)
$$
which yields the inequality which was to be proven.

For the second inequality, $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ and thus $f'(x)=2xe^{x^2}$ so that with the same argument as above, I get
$$
2ye^{y^2}\geqslant\frac{e^{y^2}-e^{x^2}}{y-x}
$$

I don't see where the factor $x+y$ comes into play. It seems to me that I need another estimate which replaces the factor $2y$ on the left-hand side by $x+y$, but since $2y\geqslant x+y$, I do not see a helpful upper estimate.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the mean-value theorem to $f(x) = e^x$ (instead of $e^{x^2}$):
$$
 e^{y^2}-e^{x^2} = f(y^2)-f(x^2) = (y^2-x^2) f'(z) = (y-x)(x+y)e^z
$$
for some $z \in (x^2, y^2)$, and the desired inequality follows.

Comment: Ah, the inequality then just follows by $e^z\leq e^y$.

Comment: $e^z \le e^{y^2}$, actually.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful